# ¿Por qué str == "value" evalúa a falso cuando asigno var str = value?

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de desarrollar un código javascript. Lo que intento es asignarle una cadena a una variable, y luego comprobar si son iguales.

Código:

```js
var value;
var str = value;
var booleano = str == "value"
ta.innerHTML = booleano
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id=ta></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Yo le asigno la variable `"value"` a la variable `str`, pero cuando voy a comprobar `str == value` evalúa a falso.

¿Por qué pasa esto? ¿Qué debería hacer para que efectivamente sean iguales?

Traté con `equals` de esta forma `str.equals("value")` pero me marca error.

> VM1528:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'equals' of undefined(…)

... y de esta otra forma, `equals(str,"value")`, pero me marca otro error.

> VM1531:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: equals is not defined(…)

Comment: prueba con equals()

Comment: var value es distinto a "value"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debes tener cuenta que var value es distinto a "value", en el primero has creado una variable llamada value sin asignarle un valor, el segundo es un string con valor "value"

```js
var value;
var str = "value";
var booleano = str == "value";
ta.innerHTML = booleano;
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id=ta></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

A ver...analizando tu codigo:

```
    1) var value;
    2) var str = value;
    3) var booleano = str == "value"
```

En la linea 1 creaste una variable con nombre value, sin valor, con lo cual su valor es undefined.
En la linea 2, creaste una variable con nombre str y el asignaste el valor de value, que es undefined.
En la linea 3, creaste una variable con nombre booleano que le estas asignado el la comparacion entre str, cuyo valor es undefined y el string "value". Obviamente, cualquier valor comparado con undefined es FALSO.
Espero te ayude!

Answer (score 1):

La lógica de tu código es esta:

declarando la variable

```
var value; //donde value = undefined || null
```

Ahora estas asignando a `str` la variable `value`

```
var str = value; //donde str = undefined || null
```

Comparamos si `str` es igual a `"value"`;
Aquí implican varias cosas:

1. `str` no tiene valor asignado realmente se encuentra indefinida (`undefined`)
2. `"value"` es una variable de tipo `string`

Ahora lo que quieres hacer es comparación si son iguales y como una es `undefined` y la otra es un `string` no llegaran a ser iguales

```
var booleano = str == "value"
```

**La solución es asignarle a la primera linea `"value"` o bien la segunda linea la asignación volverla cadena**